# Is there a way to check which process reads/writes to HDD right now?

Tags: hard-drive, performance-monitor

MY HDD is reading something, but I have no idea what. Is there an app I can use to monitor processes which read/write to HDD and where they read/write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:

Press Ctrl+Shift+ESC;
Go to "Performance" menu;
Go to "Resource Monitor";
It will popup another windows. On this window select "Disk".

This is where you can see which process are using more or less disk I/O operations.

Comment: great ! Is there such a feature for linux?

Comment: For linux I dont know the right way, but maybe you can find something using "ps", "top" or even "hdparm".

Comment: lsof under Linux will give you reporting on what files are open and to what processess they belong. It is quite extensive and have quite a lot of command options to report different things (such as what processes are listening on what ports).